# Unhappiness due to revived corpses

Tags: fallout-shelter

I had a person die in the diner, and revived him after quite some time. Now everyone that wasn't dead is unhappy because there's "a corpse in the room" but there isn't. He's alive working next to them. Any remedies? Game glitch?

Comment: Have you tried moving the revived dweller out of the room and then back in?

Comment: I tried moving the revived dweller out and back in, all of the people who were present, out and back in. And even replaced all the unhappy dwellers with other dwellers, they began to lose their unhappiness as well.

Comment: I had to remove the whole fully upgraded dinner 3-square just to fix it. What a waste of caps.

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution for this (I think) but it requires more testing.

First, find the dweller who died in the room. You can usually tell because s/he's happy to be working in it, but anyone else who works there becomes miserable.

Keep rushing until you get a radroach infestation. This should not be difficult. Don't let it spread, but let it kill the dweller who died.

Immediately revive the dweller, then solve the radroach problem. I don't think order matters but that's how I did it. After a revive, room should work as normal.

Tested on one of my screwed up rooms and this seemed to work. Have one more to try it on, will report back if results differ.

Comment: I also encountered this problem and this solved it for me. It didn't take long too long to figure out which dweller it was, and after letting him die and reviving, it took only a few minutes to see their happiness go flying back up. Edit: For what it's worth, this was also in my diner.

Comment: Currently have this bug in my Fitness Studio. Can't rush, and all 6 of them complain about the corpse. So I've taken away their weapons. I'll let em all die next invasion, before I demolish and kiss those caps goodbye.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a bug, however you can effectively "reset" the label mis-representing your dweller as dead.

1. Look for the dweller who had previously died. This will likely be the dweller with the highest happiness in that group.
2. Send the other dwellers into a nearby room.
3. Continuously rush the room with your buggy dweller, so that incidents break out, and let your buggy dweller die.
4. Bring all the other dwellers back into the room, while your buggy dweller is still dead.
5. Revive the buggy dweller.

It appears that other dwellers can still perceive a newly-resurrected dweller as dead. However, repeating the above process has fixed the issue, for me.

Answer (score 3):

I destroyed that room (I had it on 3rd lvl and 3 rooms merged) and build it again. Fixed the problem. Problem isnt dwellers only the room.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a suggestion:

1. restart the game (close it from background, lock your phone, unlock it and start it again). Normally this should get it back to normal.
2. try to move the undead dweller to another room or better, send him in the outlands and call him back.

Normally this should work.

Comment: I tried all of the above suggestions, still hasn't reset for me. I'd hate to have to demolish the diner just to increase happiness and productivity

Comment: But can you move him to another room? Do the people in the newer room say it too? Are they said about the dead man too?

Comment: I can move him. Post him out in the wasted and have him come home. Have him work in other rooms. He can even be present in the room he died in and not be affected. No other room is he deemed a "corpse" and present or not. The group comments about a corpse in the diner

Comment: Another idea is to move the people out of the dinner to another room and move them back. Maybe those are broken. Not the undead one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! For me it was solved when I upgraded the room next to it and the two rooms merged.