# Fallout shelter - Constantly complaining about dead bodies

Tags: fallout-shelter

So i had a bad couple of days and after a particularly nasty fire in my main power room, then a radroach infestation (again in power room) and finally raiders attacking and power room taking the brunt of the raider attack I accidentally allowed 2 vault dwellers to die. As i had just spent a large amount upgrading rooms I did not immediately have enough to revive them... I sent a couple of high level dwellers into the wasteland and concentrated my effort on getting caps to revive them. I would say they were dead for about 3/4 hours. Obviously this affected the other dwellers in the room happiness levels but as power, food and water were all by this point green i did not think it would be too long for them to recover. 
It has now been 48hrs+ since the dwellers were revived yet the occupants in this room are still terribly unhappy and can still be seen making complaints about dead bodies in the work place.

I have tried so far...

1. Moving staff to another room like living quarters one at a time.
2. Moving affected characters into the wasteland for an hour or so.
3. Swapping the dwellers with other dwellers in the building.

1 + 2 have exactly the same result. In both cases the affected dweller will recover happiness up to 100% while they are out of the room. As soon as they are place back in the affected room they will start complaining about bodies and happiness will go down 
3 Does actually seem to cure the problem as long as I don't then swap them back which is really kind of annoying as it means i can't use the people with the best SPECIAL stats where they are most useful..

Has anyone encountered this at all? Bug?

tl:dr; some dwellers died, got revived any now the other people who were in that room still think they are dead even when moved out of the room and back in

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss a dead body? Or any other dweller is fine except those that were in the room while the dead bodies were there? Unsure if that's what you describe on the result of point 3.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the game. Other stuck state stuff like this I was able to resolve by rebooting my ipad. Hopefully an official fix is on the way.

Comment: I have encountered this problem today.  A molerat infestation took most of my vault down while they were rad-compromised due to low water.  I revived everyone over a 15-minute span, but two dwellers kept complaining when working in a cleared restaurant.  I have shut down and restarted, and it still happens.  I plan to destroy and rebuild the room.

Answer (score 1):

I have built a number of vaults and have never experienced anything like this. It is quite possible that a body collapsed near a wall and fell into the 'outside the room' space, or perhaps that you have exceeded the 'max number of rendered bodies in room' variable and is now *haunting the room*... Click the gear on the top left to check your vault roster. Look for anyone who is dead (but may be invisible) here... Clicking on them here should allow you to revive or remove them. Alternately: Try rebuilding the room elsewhere and deleting the original room. If the game complains about 'two rooms being connected' then try connecting nearby rooms to each-other via elevators to rooms on another floor. If the affected room doesn't go away after deleting it, you may have to start over from scratch to reclaim the space.

tl:dr; Your room **may be cursed**. If you can't track down the body, and you can't delete the room, delete the vault.

**Edit:** It also [has been suggested](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/225883/115560) that one or more dwellers who have died in the accursed room may have no problem working in that room. As another possible solution, track down all such people, and *sacrifice them to the Radroach deity* (rush the room until an incident occurs and they are killed in the incident). After reviving them a second time, the revive may stick and the curse may be lifted.

Out of curiosity, did you revive these people DURING the incident? I can't say I've ever done that. It might be a clue as to why this bug happens.