# Fallout shelter dwellers unhappy because on non-existant dead body

Tags: fallout-shelter

The dwellers in my water treatement plant were all on 20% happiess - at first it was one person then everyone else I put there kept going lower. Then I zoom in and theyre saying things like "working next to a corpse isn't helping with production" or "it smells like something died in here... Oh". The problem is, there isn't any dead radroach etc. in that room and tapping blindly isn't doing anything. I've closed the app and my iPad multiple times but nothing works.

Comment: This isn't because of a dead Radroach, it 's because of a dead Dweller. Check behind all the pillars etc to see if there is a dweller that needs to be revived/removed, or check the room's roster to see if there is a dead dweller on the list (Quite obvious, they have a "dead face", "x" for eyes etc).

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/224935/108003